# Creating an ArrayList using a Scanner

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am working on a project to create a list of students using an Array List. I know how to create a simple array list, however, I decided that I want to use the Scanner method. Unfortunately, THAT is where my troubles begin. Here is what my origin class looks like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Used to create a single student.
 */

public class Student
{
private String Name;
private int Age;
private String Gender;
private int heightInches; //inches%maxInches
private int heightFeet; //inches/maxInches
private int Inches;
private final int maxInches = 12;
private int Weight;
private String Position;
private Scanner keybd;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public Student(){
    keybd = new Scanner(System.in);
    setStudent();
}

/**
 * Method to create a student
 */
public void setStudent(){
    System.out.println("Enter name of student:");
    Name = keybd.next();
    System.out.println("Enter age of student:");
    Age = keybd.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter gender of student:");
    Gender = keybd.next();
    System.out.println("Enter height in inches of student:");
    Inches = keybd.nextInt();
    if(Inches>= maxInches){
        heightFeet = Inches/maxInches;
        heightInches = Inches%maxInches;
    }
    else{
        heightInches = Inches%maxInches;}
    System.out.println("Enter position of user:");
    Position = keybd.next();
    System.out.println("Enter weight of student:");
    Weight = keybd.nextInt();
}

/**
 * Returns height of student
 */
public void getHeight(){
    System.out.println(heightFeet + "'" + heightInches + "''");
}

/**
 * Prints details of student
 */
public void printDetails(){
    if((Position.equals("Doctor")) || (Position.equals("Coach"))){
        System.out.println(Name + " who is a " + Age + " year old " + Gender + " weighs " + Weight + " and is ");
        getHeight();}
    else{System.out.println(Name + " who is a " + Age + " year old " + Gender + " is ");
        getHeight();
    }
}
```

}

Unfortunately, when I try calling the setStudent method in my new class which will be calling the Students class in order to actually make a list, I run into issues. I really wanted to have an "if" statement along with a Scanner that if the user desires to add another student it would loop, otherwise it would end, however, since I cant even create a new student using the above code, it is not even worth my time to try attempting that yet.

Comment: What issues are you running into?

Comment: I think the job of setStudent function is to set info of a student not students. why do not you move the logic you want in somewhere else?

Comment: @Eran - nothing happens

Comment: @KickButtowski - I meant student as opposed to students

Comment: Do you have a main method? What is it doing?

Comment: @TisMe but you can create a student out of your student class not students do not you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Each Student object is its own instance of the Student class. When you read all that data in the constructor, you work with that particular Student object. You could make a loop in the constructor, creating new Student objects, but that would be fairly confusing -- after all, a constructor's job is to create *one* object.

(That aside, it's bad style to have the constructor ask the user for input. It makes the class untestable in unit testing, and it ties it to a console, making it unusable in a GUI program. You'd be better off by reading all the student data elsewhere, and then passing it to the Student constructor.)

So, some code *outside* the Student class, e.g., your main method) should have the list of Students, collect the input, and create the Student objects.

Comment: The setStudent method was going to be part of a different method to add students to the list (besides predefined ones)

Comment: @TisMe to me, you try to make your life complicated that is all

Comment: @KickButtowski unfortunately that's just how I roll (sadly I overthink things)

Comment: @TisMe it is ok as long as you are not close minded. read the answer try to follow that you gonna be fine. robert answer is awesome

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try keeping it simple (first time in a long while that I took the simple way out)
In my new class I put this:

```
/**
 * Method to add more students
 */
public void addStudent(){
    studentList.add  (new Student());
}
```

On the bright side, now I can try using an if-else method to add more students.